# Implement selection from array by 'random' or 'if/elif conditionals'

Tags: python, array, python-3.x, random

I'm working on some code examples in 'Automate the boring stuff in python...' to prepare for my first year of CS. I want to know if its better to use an array with random selection below or rather multiple if/elif conditionals to generate output. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

```
import sys
import random
import time

answer = ['It is certain', 'It is so', 'Try later', 'Ask Again', 'Not good', 'Doubtful']
r = random.randint(0,5)

def getAnswer():
    print (answer[r])

def Main():
    try = input('Try your luck. Yes or no.\n')
    if try == 'yes':
        getAnswer()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('May luck be on your side.')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array is clean and easy to read, and it takes up much less space than an army of if/elif/else statements. In my opinion, what you have is much better than the alternative.

That said, there are a couple of things that could be changed.

First, either move the random selection into the `getAnswer()` function, or change the function to accept an argument. What if you decide later on that you want to get multiple answers? Even if you only call `getAnswer()` once, making one of these changes will make the function's job clearer.

Second, remove the hard-coded array length in the `random.randint()` arguments. If you later add or remove answers, the arguments to `randint()` need to be changed, too. This can be avoided by either using `random.choice()` (ideal if `getAnswer()` doesn't take any arguments) or by using `random.randint(0, len(answer) - 1)` or `random.randrange(len(answer))`.

`randrange()` is typically preferred over `randint()`. Everything else in Python treats ranges as including the start index and *excluding* the end index, but `randint()` *includes* the end index. Not only does that make `randint()` inconsistent with everything else, but it also makes working with lists and sequences more error-prone (notice how clean and neat `randrange(len(my_list))` is compared to `randint(0, len(my_list) - 1)`?).

Here is how these changes might look (along with one or two other changes, unrelated to how the random selection is made).

**Option 1: Random selection inside of getAnswer():**

```
import sys
import random
import time

ANSWERS = ['It is certain', 'It is so', 'Try later', 'Ask Again', 'Not good', 'Doubtful']

def getAnswer():
    print (random.choice(ANSWERS))

def Main():
    prompt_string = 'Try your luck. Yes or no.\n'
    while input(prompt_string).strip().lower() in ('yes', 'y')
        prompt_string = 'Try again (yes or no)?\n'
        getAnswer()

    print('May luck be on your side.')
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**Option 2: getAnswer() takes an argument**

```
import sys
import random
import time

ANSWERS = ['It is certain', 'It is so', 'Try later', 'Ask Again', 'Not good', 'Doubtful']

def getAnswer(chosen_index):
    print (ANSWERS[chosen_index])

def Main():
    prompt_string = 'Try your luck. Yes or no.\n'
    while input(prompt_string).strip().lower() in ('yes', 'y')
        prompt_string = 'Try again (yes or no)?\n'
        getAnswer(random.randrange(len(ANSWERS)))

    print('May luck be on your side.')
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Thanks, these are great suggestions to further clean up my code and learn some good programming practices.